# Error importing Node.js modules into Intern tests

Tags: node.js, intern

I'm trying out Intern for testing our Node.js modules. I've got it set up to run an empty test and even `require` node modules, but when I try to `require` one of the modules in our package I get the error:

```
/path/to/app/node_modules/path/path.js:327
  var path = (i >= 0) ? arguments[i] : process.cwd();
                                               ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Object.exports.resolve (/path/to/app/node_modules/path/path.js:327:52)
  at Object.exports.relative (/path/to/app/node_modules/path/path.js:405:20)
  at getSource (/path/to/app/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:368:21)
  at formatLine (/path/to/app/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:405:40)
  at processChromeTrace (/path/to/app/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:418:16)
  at normalizeStackTrace (/path/to/app/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:470:38)
  at Object.getErrorMessage (/path/to/app/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:597:14)
  at PreExecutor._handleError (/path/to/app/node_modules/intern/lib/executors/PreExecutor.js:256:24)
  at /path/to/app/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/lang.js:78:32
  at process.<anonymous> (/path/to/app/node_modules/intern/lib/executors/PreExecutor.js:302:6)
```

Folder structure is:

- src/

  - **/*.coffee
- tests

  - unit/**/*.coffee
  - intern.js
- js/ (coffeescript is compiled here)

  - src/

    - **/*.js
  - tests/

    - **/*.js
    - all.js (compiled by rolling up the names of the other tests under `/js/tests`)
- node_modules

Here's my intern.js:

```
define({
  capabilities: {
    'browserstack.selenium_version': '2.45.0'
  },

  environments: [
    {browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '11', platform: 'WIN8'},
    {browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '10', platform: 'WIN8'},
    {browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '9', platform: 'WINDOWS'},
    {browserName: 'firefox', version: '37', platform: ['WINDOWS', 'MAC']},
    {browserName: 'chrome', version: '39', platform: ['WINDOWS', 'MAC']},
    {browserName: 'safari', version: '8', platform: 'MAC'}
  ],

  maxConcurrency: 2,
  tunnel: 'BrowserStackTunnel',
  loaderOptions: {
    packages: [{name: 'app', location: 'js/src'}]
  },
  reporters: ['Console', 'Lcov'],
  suites: ['js/tests/unit/all'],
  excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:\.npm|js\/tests|src|tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

My test is just:

```
define (require) ->
  registerSuite = require('intern!object')
  assert = require('intern/chai!assert')
  SchemaBuilder = require('intern/dojo/node!app/path/to/Module')

  registerSuite
    name: 'Testing'

    'test': ->
```

From the project root I'm running `'./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/intern'`

Is this a problem with my code, configuration, environment, or Intern?

I've tried with Node.js v0.12.0 and v0.12.7.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, removing the `path` module from my app dependencies (`package.json`) resolved (well, avoided) the `undefined is not a function` error, seemingly falling back on Intern's own path resolution. I don't really know why, but this seems like a bug.

This presented a new, more tractable error: `Error: Cannot find module 'app/path/to/Module'`, suggesting the path in the `require()` was simply wrong.

I think the problem is that the `intern/dojo/node` loader doesn't support the `loaderOptions: {packages: [{name: 'app', location: 'js/src'}]}` configuration, and hence it is searching for an `app` directory relative to the test module. If I replace `app/` with `../../../../js/src/` then it resolves and works as expected.

It's a bit ugly, but it's the standard way of requiring local files in node, so it's also not too surprising, I had just hoped Intern's loader could make it cleaner.